# Where are background images stored by Variety?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, variety

I'd like to know where all the backgrounds (or at least the favourites) downloaded by Variety are stored.

Comment: Did you look at https://peterlevi.com/variety/2014/05/variety-and-kde/?

Comment: I followed the instructions, but it does not work. The wallpaper.jpg file reamins unchanged.

Comment: Did you try [under `~/.config/variety/Downloaded`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmvDM.png)?